# Why is the os.path.join() in directory giving an invalid directory name error?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

Here it should create the folder naming Model 1 at time but it giving an error message.

```
# Folder for tensorboard
folder_name = f'Model 1 at {strftime("%H:%M")}'
directory = os.path.join('tensorboard_mnist_digit_logs', folder_name)
try:
    os.makedirs(directory)
except OSError as exception:
    print(exception.strerror)
else:
    print('Successfully created directories!')
```

Comment: You can't have a colon `:` in a directory name on Windows. It can appear only directly after the drive letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not have `':'` in a folder name.

Change `strftime("%H:%M") to strftime("%H-%M")` and it will work